# tkinter - mainloop() frozen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to get real time input from the user. Based on Yes/No, user will be asked to select the date from the datepicker. Once the date is selected, program will assign the date to the global variables todays_date, yesterdays_date.

Problem here is it doesn't move further to the next line of code "print('final status')". Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def invoke_date(Var1,root):
    root.withdraw()
    root.quit()
    global todays_date, yesterdays_date
    if Var1.get() == 2:
        def cal_done():
            top.withdraw()
            root_date.quit()
        root_date = tk.Tk()
        root_date.withdraw()
        top = tk.Toplevel(root_date)    
        cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', cursor="hand1")
        cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(top, text="OK", command=cal_done).pack()
        root_date.mainloop()
        todays_date = cal.selection_get()
        yesterdays_date = todays_date - timedelta(days = 1)
    else:        
        todays_date = datetime.now()
        yesterdays_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Report Dialog Box")
tk.Label(root, text="Do you want to run the report for today's date?:",justify = tk.LEFT,padx = 20).pack()
Var1 = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Yes", padx = 20,variable = Var1,value = 1).pack(anchor=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "No", padx = 20,variable = Var1,value = 2).pack(anchor=tk.W)
tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = lambda: invoke_date(Var1,root)).pack()    
root.mainloop()

print('final status')
```

Comment: `tkinter` works by having its own event system to run the GUI. To enter this you call the `mainloop()` method which blocks until the program exits. Why do you want to print something?

Comment: `root_date.mainloop()` exists only when every instance of `tk.Tk()` and `tk.Toplevel` has been closed. Why not put the `todays_date = cal.selection_get()` and `yesterdays_date = todays_date - timedelta(days = 1)` inside the `cal_done`?

Comment: thanks quamrana for your response. print statement is just an example. Originally there are other lines of code after this.

Comment: @TheLizzard, thanks for your response. Yes i have closed them.        
  root.withdraw()
  root.quit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Instead of using `.withdraw()` then `.quit()` just use `.destroy()`.

Your corrected code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def invoke_date(Var1,root):
    root.destroy()
    global todays_date, yesterdays_date
    if Var1.get() == 2:
        def cal_done():
            root_date.destroy()
        root_date = tk.Tk() 
        cal = Calendar(root_date, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', cursor="hand1")
        cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(root_date, text="OK", command=cal_done).pack()
        root_date.mainloop()
        todays_date = cal.selection_get()
        yesterdays_date = todays_date - timedelta(days = 1)
    else:        
        todays_date = datetime.now()
        yesterdays_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Report Dialog Box")
tk.Label(root, text="Do you want to run the report for today's date?:",justify = tk.LEFT,padx = 20).pack()
Var1 = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Yes", padx = 20,variable = Var1,value = 1).pack(anchor=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "No", padx = 20,variable = Var1,value = 2).pack(anchor=tk.W)
tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = lambda: invoke_date(Var1,root)).pack()    
root.mainloop()

print('final status')
```

I also removed the `Toplevel` because you can just use `root_date`.